# Stack overflow while saving Backbone.js model

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a simple Backbone.js model:

```
class Avia.Student extends Backbone.Model
```

Told you it was simple :-)  Anyhow, I'm saving it in the following view (snipped for clarity):

```
class Avia.StudentView extends Backbone.View

  render: =>
    html = JST['views/student_view_template'](model: @model)
    @el.html(html)
    Backbone.ModelBinding.bind(@)
    $('#save').bind('click', @save)

  save: (e) =>
    e.preventDefault()
    @model.save(
        success: =>,
        error: =>
    )
```

When I click the save button, @save() is called, but fails with the following error (again, snipped for clarity as obviously it continues for a long time):

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
Backbone.Events.trigger:117
_.extend._onModelEvent:635
Backbone.Events.trigger:117
_.extend._onModelEvent:635
Backbone.Events.trigger:117
_.extend._onModelEvent:635
Backbone.Events.trigger:117
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I don't understand why this is happening ...

Comment: Yea, try commenting out the Backbone.ModelBinding.bind(@) line and see what happens

Comment: Is `#save` an element within `@el`? Are you *sure*? Because if it's elsewhere, then you're binding *another* `click` event to it on each render...

Comment: Thanks - I've commented out `Backbone.ModelBinding.bind(@)` and ensured `#save` is unique by renaming it to `#wooble` and renaming the associated bindings.  I'm still encountering the same problem :-/

Comment: I've also tried using the very latest `backbone.js` from GitHub, and the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `super()` in your collection's and/or model's constructor (if you have defined any). I had the same issue a couple of days ago: Omitting calling `super()` fails to bind the `_onModelEvent` object to the collection, which causes it to be invoked in an incorrect context (`this` is pointing to the model instead of the collection [and vice versa]).

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the save function to the view.

You do this by calling `_.bindAll` in the view's initialize method

```
class Avia.StudentView extends Backbone.View

  initialize: =>
    _.bindAll(@, 'save');
```